# User properties from Firebase Analytics in DebugView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I put some user properties in my android code such as:
(https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/properties)

```
mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("easy_account_connected", "true");
```

Then, I checked debug view and nothing appears whereas if there is a break point, my code stopped on this instruction. I can't understand, in my code there are other places where we can find these properties and sometimes it works (I see it in debug view) and sometimes, nothing.

Is it normal ?

I have found nothing on firebase website which could tell me debug view is not perfect but data are correctly saved ...

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#seconds_stream

### EDIT :

With the help of adbitx, I discovered user properties are sent with event so I made a new use case.
2 events (login / logout) and one user properties (easy_account_connected). In login case, I send :

```
mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("easy_account_connected", "true");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("login", null);
```

and in logout case, I send :

```
mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("easy_account_connected", "false");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("logout", null);
```

Here is the result in debug view
[image: login Ok / logout Nok]

Login works whereas logout does not...

Comment: Any news about it?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Last time I tested, the error was still here but it was almost 7 months ago

Comment: I faced it today... I wrote a post and to firebase support

Comment: did you get any response from support @Alexander?

Comment: @DavidMiguel yes, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50813677/4981515

Answer (score 2):

I was running into a similar issue.
I found that sending the app to the background was a way to "flush" the cache of user properties on the device and send them through to Firebase. I could then see them appear in DebugView.
Without sending the app to the background I would see event after event appear in DebugView, but no user property updates.

Comment: Thank you so much, I could have spend weeks on this! How did you find out about that cache?

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe, it looks like you only have that line and no other events. It would be nice to know whether you send any events after setting the user property. The user property comes with each event after it is set. Therefore, you need to send some events and click on one of the events in the debug view to see the user property under User Properties tab.

Comment: I didn't specify but in my app, all screen view are tagged with `setCurrentScreen()` and I have no problem with that (~20 tags). DebugView works as expected and I see all my tags but with user properties it does not work everytime. Is there a link in the doc which explains user property comes with each event after it is set ?

Comment: It is stated in the official doc as "After you set a user property value, it will be associated with every event logged afterwards, so that you gain the ability to filter all of your analytics reports by this user property". You can see it at https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317519?hl=en

Comment: Ok ! Thank you for the information but it seems problem persists (see my post edit)

Comment: Are you clicking on the login event or logout event on the screenshot?