# Firebase analytics displays incorrect data in DebugView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

I'm using Firebase Analytics. I registered two user properties and I have two custom events, each events includes 3 to 50 different options options. I met the problem that when I set the user property, very often DebugView displays the old user property for the event or is not displayed at all. Sometimes it works correctly. Please tell me how it can be fixed?

My code.

```
final class FirebaseAnalyticsManager {

    enum ScreenType {
        case editStoryScreen, homeScreen, previewStoryScreen, storeItemPreviewScreen

        var name: String {
            switch self {
            case .editStoryScreen:
                return "Edit Story Screen"
            case .homeScreen:
                return "Home Screen"
            case .previewStoryScreen:
                return "Preview Story Screen"
            case .storeItemPreviewScreen:
                return "Store Item Preview Screen"
            }
        }
    }

    enum Event {
        case templateSelected, mediaExport

        var name: String {
            switch self {
            case .templateSelected:
                return "TemplateSelected"
            case .mediaExport:
                return "MediaExport"
            }
        }
    }

    enum MediaExportDestination {
        case story, page, pageToInstagram

        var name: String {
            switch self {
            case .story:
                return "Story"
            case .page:
                return "Page"
            case .pageToInstagram:
                return "PageToInstagram"
            }
        }
    }

    private enum Keys: String {
        case exportType, templateName
    }

    private init() { }
    static let shared = FirebaseAnalyticsManager()

    open func trackScreen(_ screenType: ScreenType, screenClass: String?) {
        Analytics.setScreenName(screenType.name, screenClass: screenClass)
    }

    private func trackEvent(_ event: Event, parameters: [String : NSObject]?) {
        Analytics.logEvent(event.name, parameters: parameters)
    }

    open func trackTemplateSelected(_ templateName: String) {
        let key = Keys.templateName.rawValue
        Analytics.setUserProperty(templateName, forName: key)
        var parameters = [String : NSObject]()
        parameters[key] = templateName as NSObject
        trackEvent(.templateSelected, parameters: parameters)
    }

    open func trackMediaExport(_ destination: MediaExportDestination) {
        let key = Keys.exportType.rawValue
        Analytics.setUserProperty(destination.name, forName: key)
        var parameters = [String : NSObject]()
        parameters[key] = destination.name as NSObject
        trackEvent(.mediaExport, parameters: parameters)
    }

}
```

In this event, all data is correct.
[image]
[image]

In this event, the data is incorrect, since it should be Template5 in userProperties.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase team answered to me

**Hi there,
I just got an update from our engineers confirming that it is indeed a bug in our end. They are already working on a fix for this issue, but I can’t share details or timeline as to when this will be fixed. Please keep tabs on our release notes for any updates regarding this.**

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen do you know whether in the meanwhile its already fixed? I am also seeing this happening in my project and am wondering if its a bug on my side or if the issue is still there @ Firebase... do you know its a bug in the debugView only (and thus analytics are correct) or are the analytics also affected?

Comment: @Alexander  Did you experience the same behaviour on the production version as well or was it seen only on debug view?

Comment: @UriAbramson I had such a problem in both cases (debug and release). I haven't checked yet whether Firebase fixed this bug or not.

Comment: @Alexander any news on this?

Comment: @look1n no news

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for response, did you file any kind of issue into Google issue tracker?

Comment: @look1n No, I only reported to Firebase support.